# Where the Nickname is being used in WordPress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, users, user-meta, profiles

I see most of the place is using the "**Display name**", so why I need to set a Nickname?

Where it is being used?

Comment: Just to tie up loose ends, it would be great if you stopped by and marked Milo's answer correct.

Answer (score 12):

You technically don't have to set a nickname, it will be filled with your username if you clear the field out.

Display name is selectable between the user's username, first name, last name, first/last, or last/first, or nickname. The nickname exists to give you an option to set display name to something other than your username or real name.